# shell wrapper script to run a python file

Tags: python, shell

I thought this was going to be something much easier but I'm struggling a lot to create a shell wrapper script to be able to run a python file through my terminal. I'm using this as my wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
python3 -u index.py "$@"
```

And I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
```

I have granted permissions to both the wrapper and the python file with the following commands:

```
chmod +x dag
chmod u+x index.py
```

I'm tryng to do all of this in Windows, in case that is important. And I have python installed and in my PATH so that it's recognized. Any idea? Thankssss!!!

Comment: `dos2unix index.py`. Good luck.

Comment: Editing a question in a way that makes into a completely different question _after it's been answered_ is unfair to the people who answered in its original form, and therefore not allowed.